# Measures and differential forms on manifolds

Tags: measure-theory, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold. Let $\mu$ be a (probability) measure on $M$.

What are the conditions under which $\mu$ is given by a differential form on $M$? I imagine some sort of compatibility of the topology or the differentiable structure of $M$ with the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$ would be required.

(Apologies if the question is too elementary for this forum. A pointer to the relevant result in the literature would suffice.)

Comment: If you mean by a top degree differential form (so assume $M$ orientable) then I’d look at [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Generalizations_2) with respect to the manifold’s [natural measure class](https://books.google.com/books?id=qlpb2mWYmfYC&ots=eh8wOgplj0&pg=PA101&dq=%22natural+measure+class%22).

Comment: The answer to the question will vary depending on whether we want the (top degree) differential form to be smooth, differentiable, continuous, or merely measurable, whether or not we demand that its integral be finite, etc.

Comment: @JohnBaez, I am primarily interested in the smooth case, although the fuller picture would be good to see as well if possible. And yes, I mean top degree differential form on orientable $M$. We can even assume $M$ is compact or has finite volume if needed. Francois, thanks for the clarification and reference!

Comment: Your measure will be a continuous functional on $C^\infty(M)$, hence it is by definition a distributional section of the $\Lambda^{top}M$ bundle (aka a distribution). Now you just need a condition under which this distribution is represented by a smooth function. That really depends on what information you have available. Sledgehammer approach: check that the singular support (or the wave front set) is empty.

Comment: For the sake of precision in what @IgorKhavkine describes, a measure is not *intrinsically* a section of $\Lambda^{top} M$, but instead one can make an identification depending on a choice of generator for $\Lambda^{top} M$. I.e. given a measure $\mu$ and a volume form $\omega$ you are talking about the operation $\alpha \mapsto \int \frac{\alpha}{\omega} \mathrm{d}\mu$

Comment: A "distributional section", as per the comment by Igor Khavkine, is also known as a (top degree / lowest dimension) *current* on $M$ ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_(mathematics)  ). The theory of currents is precisely a common generalization of measure theory and differential forms on a manifold.

Comment: @user129194 - you're not going to get a nice *measure-theoretic* characterization of measures described by *smooth* differential forms of top degree, since measure theory doesn't know much about smoothness.  Better to assume your measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure for some (hence every) Riemannian metric on your manifold and conclude using using Radon-Nikodym that it's described by an L^1 differential form.  This is the easy result, anyway, from which harder ones can be inferred.

Comment: @JohnBaez: You can ask that the measure μ has a Lie derivative with respect to any smooth vector field.  This seems to fit the OP's request for a condition that combines the differentiable structure of the manifold with the σ-algebra, and amounts to requiring the resulting measurable form to be smooth.

Comment: Asking that a measure have a Lie derivative w.r.t. all vector fields is a bit odd because while differentiation of measures makes sese, if you only want differentiability _as a measure_ then the characteristic function of an interval times dx gives a measure on R that's differentiable w.r.t. all smooth vector fields.  If we're looking for conditions that imply our measure comes from a smooth differential form then there certainly various choices of conditions that work, but I don't see any that are easier to check than "the measure comes from a smooth differential form".

Comment: @JohnBaez: The characteristic function of an interval [0,1] times dx is not differentiable with respect to the vector field ∂/∂x, for example.  Indeed, unfolding the definition of Lie derivative and applying it to compute the value of the Lie derivative of the above measure μ at the same interval [0,1], the formula for the Lie derivative requires us to compute the derivative of a function t↦μ([t,1+t]).  This function is not differentiable with respect to t because it is piecewise-linear, but not linear, therefore the Lie derivative does not exist.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov - I said that the characteristic function of an interval times dx differentiable _as a measure_, not that the characteristic function of an interval is differentiable as a function!   You can define a Lie derivative for measures and demand that the limit in the definition of derivative exist in the weak topology on the space of finite (signed) measures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume that $\mu$ is a measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets. First, on any manifold the notion of negligible set is well defined.

If $M$ is orientable  and $\mu(N)=0$ for any negligible  Borel set then  the Radon-Nikodym  theorem implies that, for any smooth volume form $\omega$ on $M$, there is a positive measurable  function $\rho_\omega\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\mu(U)=\int_U \rho_\omega \omega, $$

for any open set $U\subset M$.

Comment: @BenMcKay You are right.

Answer (score 5):

Any smooth manifold has a canonical σ-ideal of negligible subsets,
and μ must vanish on these.

Apart from that, the Lie derivative of μ with respect to any smooth vector field
must exist.

This is how smooth measures are defined by Ramanan in Definition 1.9 of Chapter 3 of Global Calculus, for example.

Remark 2.8 in Chapter 8 there explains how this definition
is equivalent to the traditional definition of a smooth measure as a smooth section
of the line bundle of densities.